# "синтаксическая ошибка при анализе пакета"

Tags: android, apk, generate, android-debug

Написал приложение, установил в качестве эмулятора физическое устройство, то есть отлаживал через телефон. Теперь решил собрать apk-debug для установки на смартфон, без play market, но для начала удаляю старую версию, которая загружалась через студию, и появляется данная ошибка (в заголовок). В чем может быть дело? Версия андроида на телефоне 5.1

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.personal.anton.notes"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

Comment: defaultConfig {  - открыта скобка, но не закрыта. Явно поехала структура gradle-файла

Comment: Вы ошибаетесь, была бы ошибка при компиляции пакет бы не собрался! Это ошибка при копировании...

Comment: @Roman Все скобки закрыты. Конкретно дефолтКонфиг закрыта перед билдТайпс.

Comment: @Эникейщик Упс, сорян, не по глазам было